# What does the r flag do for update-package

Tags: nuget

```
Update-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform -r
```

What does the `r` flag do? I would guess reinstall, but I can't find this documented anywhere. The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages) doesn't appear to mention it anywhere, but I have seen it suggested to be used in a few other answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for the [Update-Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/ps-reference/ps-ref-update-package#parameters) only lists a single parameter starting with the letter `r`. PowerShell only requires you to specify arguments to the point that it's not ambiguous, hence `-r`, `-re`, `-rei`, `-rein`, `-reins`, `-reinst`, `-reinsta`, `-reinstal` and `-reinstall` all are equivalent.

On the other hand, there is more than one argument starting with `i`, hence `-i` will not work, it's necessary to provide at least enough letters until it's no longer ambiguous.

This is the reason that the single letter arguments are not documented. PowerShell works differently to Unix commands, and Update-Package doesn't itself explicitly support the single letter argument. It's just the shell that auto-fills on behalf of the user.

So, yes, it reinstalls. Note that reinstall doesn't do anything for PackageReference, only for pacakges.config.

Comment: Fantastic answer! Thanks for that, I'm sure it'll be handy in future as well